# How to put if in OnCreate()

Tags: java, android

Hi there i have a problem error that from NextActivity cannot go to the MainActivity3. Here is the Code NextActivity

```
package com.example.java;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class NextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        TextView textView= findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);

    }

    public void onBtnClick(View view){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Intent intent1= new Intent(this,MainActivity3.class);
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        String message1 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE1);
        TextView textView= findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView plain1= findViewById(R.id.plain1);
        TextView plain2= findViewById(R.id.plain2);
        String b=plain1.getText().toString();

        if(b.equals(message.toString())&&plain2.getText().toString().equals(message1.toString())){
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
        else{
            textView.setText("Password or Username is Wrong");
        }


    }

}
```

and here is the code of MainActivity3 that cannot be open through NextActivity

```
package com.example.java;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ActionProvider;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        Intent intent= getIntent();
        String number = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity2.extraint);

        FrameLayout lay= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frames);
        if(number.equals("1")) {
            lay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else{

        }
    }

    public void onBtnClick (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

The Problem is that through the NextActivity button click the apps will restart in it's own that supposed to go to the page of MainActivity3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it by

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String number = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity2.extraint);
    if(number != null) {
        FrameLayout lay = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frames);
        if (number.equals("1")) {
            lay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {

        }
    }
    else{}

}
```

Maybe any others that have a better ways?

Comment: Actually, from `NextActivity` to `MainActivity3`, your intent has not put data into the intent so `intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity2.extraint)` will return null. So I think you should put more data in `intent1` of your `NextActivity`.

Comment: Coming from `NextActivity` to `MainActivity3` , How you can get an int from `MainActivity2`??? If you get int from `NextActivity` first you have to put int with intent.

Comment: My bad i have changed the code and problem solved i will post the code later